# Select rows having same data in field but in different casing

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in MySQL containing rows which have a field username. Now I'd like to select those rows having the same username but with different casing in the username, say kMalta and Kmalta.

How could I do this using a SELECT statement?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to catch a specific username:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE UPCASE(username) = 'KMALTA'`

If you want to catch all the rows with duplicates:

`SELECT u1.* FROM users u1, users u2 WHERE UPCASE(u1.username) = UPCASE(u2.username) AND u1.id != u2.id`

Comment: Thanks but I'd like it generic, not capture KMalta only.

Comment: So what exectly do you want to catch, all rows with username that already exists in different case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.username
FROM tab a
JOIN tab b
ON LOWER(a.username) = LOWER(b.username)
GROUP BY a.username
HAVING COUNT(a.username) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE LOWER(username) IN (

      SELECT LOWER(username)
        FROM users
    GROUP BY LOWER(username)
      HAVING COUNT(id) > 1

)
```